# Find biggest element in a String with words?

Tags: string, abap

How can I, in ABAP, split a string into n parts AND determine which one is the biggest element? In my solution I would need to know how many elements there are, but I want to solve it for WHATEVER NUMBER of elements.

I tried the below code. And i searched the web.

```
DATA: string TYPE string VALUE 'this is a string'.
DATA: part1 TYPE c LENGTH 20.
DATA: part2 TYPE c LENGTH 20.
DATA: part3 TYPE c LENGTH 20.
DATA: part4 TYPE c LENGTH 20.
DATA: del TYPE c VALUE ' '.
DATA: bigger TYPE c LENGTH 20.


split: string AT del INTO part1 part2 part3 part4.

bigger = part1.

IF bigger > part2.
  bigger = part1.
ELSEIF bigger > part3.
  bigger = part2.
ELSE.
  bigger = part4.
ENDIF.
WRITE: bigger.
```

Expected result: Works with any number of elements in a string and determines which one is biggest.

Actual result: I need to know how many elements there are

Comment: You are using the word "biggest" which may confuse people (currently, they understood "longest") but your algorithm says you want to sort alphabetically (A first, Z last) and output the last word in order ("this" in your example, because "t" is after "i", "a" and "s"). Could you please edit your question to clarify what "biggest" means?

Comment: On what basis you gonna split it? Word-wise? Character-wise? Sentence-wise?What if it has no spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it:

```
DATA: string TYPE string VALUE 'this is a string'.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_words,
         word   TYPE string,
         length TYPE i,
       END OF ty_words.
DATA: ls_words TYPE ty_words.
DATA: gt_words TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_words.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  WHILE string IS NOT INITIAL.
    SPLIT string AT space INTO ls_words-word string.
    ls_words-length = strlen( ls_words-word ).
    APPEND ls_words TO gt_words.
  ENDWHILE.
  SORT gt_words BY length DESCENDING.
  READ TABLE gt_words
       ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_longest_word>)
       INDEX 1.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    WRITE: 'The longest word is:', <ls_longest_word>-word.
  ENDIF.
```

Please note, it does not cover the case if there are more longest words with the same length, it will just show one of them.

Comment: Please note that `READ TABLE gt_words ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_longest_word>) INDEX 1.` will only work in a system that supports the inline declaration syntax. If "J. T. Random" has an older system, they need to declare it beforehand with `FIELD-SYMBOLS <ls_longest_word> TYPE ty_words.` and then use `READ TABLE gt_words ASSIGNING <ls_longest_word> INDEX 1.` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the number of splitted parts if you split the string into an array.  Then you LOOP over the array and check the string length to find the longest one.

While József Szikszai's solution works, it may be too complex for the functionality you need. This would work just as well: (also with the same limitation that it willl only output the first longest word and no other ones of the same length)

```
DATA string TYPE string VALUE 'this is a string'.
DATA parts TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.
DATA biggest TYPE string.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <part> TYPE string.

SPLIT string AT space INTO TABLE parts.

LOOP AT parts ASSIGNING <part>.

  IF STRLEN( <part> ) > STRLEN( biggest ).
    biggest = <part>.
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.

WRITE biggest.
```

Edit: I assumed 'biggest' meant longest, but if you actually wanted the word that would be last in an alphabet, then you could sort the array descending and just output the first entry like this:

```
DATA string TYPE string VALUE 'this is a string'.
DATA parts TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.
DATA biggest TYPE string.

SPLIT string AT space INTO TABLE parts.
SORT parts DESCENDING.
READ TABLE parts INDEX 1 INTO biggest.

WRITE biggest.
```

Comment: Your code is also faster, SORT is slower than a LOOP

Answer (score 2):

With ABAP 740, you can also shorten it to:

```
SPLIT lv_s AT space INTO TABLE DATA(lt_word).
DATA(lv_longest)    = REDUCE string( INIT longest = `` FOR <word> IN lt_word NEXT longest = COND #( WHEN strlen( <word> ) > strlen( longest ) THEN <word> ELSE longest ) ).
DATA(lv_alphabetic) = REDUCE string( INIT alph = ``    FOR <word> IN lt_word NEXT alph    = COND #( WHEN <word> > alph THEN <word> ELSE alph ) ).
```

Answer (score 0):

If "biggest" means "longest" word here is the Regex way to do this:

```
FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\w+' IN string RESULTS DATA(words).
SORT words BY length DESCENDING.
WRITE substring( val = string off = words[ 1 ]-offset len = words[ 1 ]-length ).
```